# Export data from yaml format to Excel

Tags: python, numpy

[image]

This image shows my data in .yaml format. I want to export in column

Comment: First result in Google Search :) https://codebeautify.org/yaml-to-excel-converter

Comment: @Tasos, Online converters are not working properly. Suggest me some codes in python.

Comment: Show us what you have done and where you are stuck. We will help you improve what you have already tried.

Comment: Please don't provide the text of your question as an image, it makes text search impossible on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
import yaml
import pandas as pd

data = """
thermal_properties:
- temp: 0.0
  free_energy: 10

- temp: 1.0
  free_energy: 11

- temp: 2.0
  free_energy: 12
"""
x = yaml.load(data)

pd.DataFrame(x['thermal_properties']).to_excel('file.xlsx')
```

should do the job.